# reset sql server to default?

Tags: sql-server-2012, configuration

I am trying to learn to mirror a test database and in the course of doing this, was typing in some commands into a query box.  While trying to create a database mirroring endpoint I submitted a command with a typo.  I was returned an error.  I tried to resubmit a corrected command, but then was told that the endpoint already existed. So then I figured I'd just delete my test database and restart. I deleted the database in my primary SQL Server, but now my mirror SQL Server shows my test database as restoring, and I am unable to delete that one.

Is there a way to undo everything that I have done, going back to a installation default of my SQL Server?  There is nothing I need to save, I'm just trying to learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To completely reset everything would involve uninstalling/reinstalling SQL Server.  But this is overkill.  Instead it sounds like you have two things you need to do.

**Thing 1**

First thing you should do is clean up your endpoints.  I would do this on both your primary and mirror server.  The [`DROP ENDPOINT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181586.aspx) command is straightforward.  If you need to see what endpoints are currently out there, you can select from [sys.endpoints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189746.aspx).

**Thing 2**

Drop your old database.  If it's stuck in recovery, the first thing to check is your [SQL Error Log](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187109.aspx) on the mirroring target and make sure it isn't actually doing anything.  You want to look for messages containing the word "Recovery" and "Step n of 3".  If these are there, it's still in the process of restoring.  Otherwise, you just need to complete the recovery with:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [foo] WITH RECOVERY;
```

Once you have completed recovery and the database is online, you should be able to drop it.

Comment: Thank you again. It worked and I'm back on track with my studies.  How can I mark your answer correct though?  (Still trying to get a handle on the way this forum works!)